# Unable to insert 'NULL' as text in SQLIte

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert text 'NULL' in SQLite table and getting `syntax error near :'NULL'`.

Below is my SQL insert statement.

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO POINTS_TABLE VALUES('NULL','NULL','NULL')");
```

Comment: Your statement works in http://sqlfiddle.com/. What programming language do you use?

Comment: Maybe try putting a space after `VALUES`?  It looks like a function call right now.

Comment: @NovaDenizen No, the space is **optional**, here. The **(** acts as a separator. The space would be `much appreciated`, but only **for readability**, not for functionality.

Comment: issue is with NULL, removed "'" enclosed the text NULL and all works fine now. @wgitscht Its SQLite 3 in android app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your code from

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO POINTS_TABLE VALUES('NULL','NULL','NULL')");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO POINTS_TABLE (COL1,COL2,Col3) VALUES ('NULL','NULL','NULL');");
```

further to this I think you want to loose the quotation marks unless you want to store the string "NULL" in these columns. if your data types for these columns are not strings then this will throw an error.